# responsive images in full width container

Tags: css, image, resize, responsive-design

hard to explain and my mind is blank! but i have a div that is full width, i then would like to put 8 images within the div that would then resize to whatever size your screen is. Sorry if this doesn't make sense does anyone have any ideas.

Comment: Let's see what have you tried...

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please describe which tools you are using. Show some code and tell us what you have tried so far. Some images of what you are trying.

Comment: i've added an image of what i mean.

Comment: i just cannot get the images to sit within the full width div and resize...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you question, here is what you need. http://jsfiddle.net/ukkJm/

Having a `div` that's 100% width, you have to make the size of each image to be `100%/8` so `12.5%`. Let me know if this is what you asked for, please!

Answer (score 0):

You can make responsive images with this in css:

```
.img-responsive{
  display:block;
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto
 }
```